# How to use syntax rules to disable spell checking certain regions?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, spell-checking

Vim has a built in capability to spell check files (see `:help spell`). This spell checking is syntax aware (see `:help syn-spell`). Unfortunately, I have no experience writing syntax rules for highlighting.

How do I add simple syntax rules to certain files that disable spell checking of certain code regions without changing the existing highlighting? What are basic ideas to approach such problems?

The following example motivates my question:

Often I use markdown-style inline code in comments in the source code. I would like to disable spell checking within the inline code in the comment delimited by the back ticks (even better would be to enable Vim script syntax highlighting there, but I guess this would deserve its own Stack Exchange question). For example, having the word `filetype` highlighted as a spelling mistake is distracting:

```
     [... some Vim script ...]
     " plug#begin() automatically runs:
     "   `filetype plugin indent on`
     "   `syntax enable`
     " Those may be reverted with:
     "   `filetype plugin indent off`
     "   `syntax off`
     [... some Vim script ...]
```

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: Yes, I have. I left some comments below your answer. Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 0):

I would enrich the vim syntax with:

```
syn match vimLineComment /".*`[^`]*`/ contains=@NoSpell
```

You could achieve that by adding the following line to your `vimrc` file:

```
autocmd Syntax vim syn match vimLineComment /".*`[^`]*`/ contains=@NoSpell
```

Alternatively (as mentioned by @BenKnoble) you could add the following line to the `~/.vim/after/syntax/vim.vim`:

```
syn match vimLineComment /".*`[^`]*`/ contains=@NoSpell
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a couple of follow up questions:
1.Is the first code line you give something I would normally put in the `after/ftplugin` directory? I.e. in `after/ftplugin/vim.vim`?
2. Would you be so kind to explain your second line? I have too many questions about it. From that line, I understand `autocmd` and the regular expression, but anything else is new to me.

Comment: You could probably drop the non-autocmd in after/syntax/vim.vim

Comment: Putting this in my `after/syntax/vim.vim` worked. However, after the inline code the rest of the comment is not properly syntax highlighted. Hence, the suggested "command?" does break existing syntax highlighting. If another inline comment appears on the same line behaviour changes as well.

After reading a little bit, including in the `syntax/vim.vim`, and the manual, a proper solution likely requires to nest the inline code as a syntax item in the syntax items for vim comments. The proposed solution likely matches instead of the syntax item for vim comments.

Comment: Or rather the proposed solution has some non-trivial interaction with the syntax items used for vim comments in `syntax/vim.vim`. Because up to and including the inline code, the highlighting rule from `syntax/vim.vim` matches. And then stops matching after the inline comment unless another backtick can be found on the same line, and so on. In other words, text after the last backtick on a line does not get matched.

Comment: After more reading, it seems to me that a correct solution for my example should be along the line of `syn match vimCommentInlineCode /\`[^\`]*\`/ contains=@NoSpell containedin=vimCommentGroup contained`. An answer to the question should briefly explain how this would work (it doesn't), what the keywords are that are used, and that the `vimCommentGroup` is optained from the`syntax/vim.vim` file, as this is where inline code is supposed to be contained. 

But this solution has the same problems as the proposed one. Likely, this is related to the `vimCommentGroup` itself containg `@Spell`.

Comment: And of course, the solution proposed in the original answer disables spell checking on the whole line, instead of only within the inline code region.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed feedback. I'll try to improve the answer :-) It would be helpful if you could illustrate the problem of the solution such that I could test the new version before publish it :-)

Comment: With `syn match vimLineComment /".*\`[^\`]*\`/ contains=@NoSpell` in `after/syntax/vim.vim` there is several problems. I need to split this illustration into several comments.

Comment: The original solution breaks the default syntax highlighting of `syntax/vim.vim` in ways I do not fully understand. First of all, `syntax/vim.vim` itself defines a syntax item `vimLineComment` as `syn match vimLineComment +^[ \t:]*".*$+ contains=@vimCommentGroup,vimCommentString,vimCommentTitle,vimComment`. Hence, the syntax item of the original solution may be overwritten likely overwrites existing syntax highligthing. At least, the highlighting is broken.

Comment: In the default `syntax/vim.vim` for the syntax item `vimLineComment` a highlighting is defined via `hi def link vimLineComment vimComment`. This highlighting rule likely now still applies `vimLineComment` after being overwritten or changed by the proposed solution. Hence, the default syntax highlighting for line comments still takes some effect.

Comment: However, the original `vimLineComment` is stronger than the version from the proposed solution. At least, the version from the proposed solution matches only up to the second backtick instead of, for example, up until the end of the line. Nevertheless, if more than two backticks are on the same comment line, behaviour is strange. Everything up to and including the last backtick on the line is matched, but not until the end of the line. Furthermore, the original `vimLineComment` interacts with other syntax items defined in `syntax/vim.vim` and it is possible that even more things are broken.

Comment: Moreover, for the newly defined `vimLineComment`, spell checking is entirely disabled. However, spell checking should only be disabled for the inline code, not the whole comment. Unfortunately, by now I believe that fixing this may be difficult because of the line `syn cluster vimCommentGroup contains=vimTodo,@Spell` in `syntax/vim.vim`, i.e. syntax items belonging to `vimCommentGroup` are defined to be spell checked. Strangely, instead of `vimLineComment` being defined as part of the cluster using `contains`, the `containedin` keyword is used, instead (which I don't understand).

Comment: I suspect that it may be impossible to define a syntax item that shouldn't be spell checked as a part of a syntax item that should be spell checked. Hence, if one syntax item is defined to `contains=@Spell,someOtherSyntaxItem` and the `someOtherSyntaxItem` is defined to `contains=@NoSpell` the first one takes precedence over the whole match and `contains=@NoSpell` is ignored.

Comment: At least, this is the behaviour observed with my non-functional solution `syn match vimCommentInlineCode /\`[^\`]*\`/ contains=@NoSpell containedin=vimCommentGroup contained`. However, I did not test other cases, yet. As I said syntax rules are a completely new area for me.

Comment: At last, my question asked for general ideas how to approach such problems, only giving the inline code in vim script problem as a motivating example. Hence, I believe an answer only discussing the example is insufficient. However, by now, I understand that the inline code in vim script problem is non-trivial to begin with, as the definition of the syntax items for vim script comments in `syntax/vim.vim` is quite involved. Hence, this motivating example may be too difficult to begin with.

Comment: By now, I understand much more about the problem than I did before. Hence, later I may assist in adding basic information for readers without familiarity with syntax rules.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot: Since the very nature of inline code as an syntax item is to be nested in a vim comment. Hence, a syntax rule for such inline code likely needs to interact with the existing syntax rules to follow best practises. More generally, by now I believe that general approaches to such problems often involve interacting with existing syntax rules. By now, I believe the question is rather difficult to answer.